# How to convert an rtf file using rtf2latex2e?

Tags: word-to-latex

I am trying to convert a pdf file to latex. For which (after looking the answers to several such questions in this site) I downloaded `rtf2latex2e` (the winzip files). But I can't figure out how to produce the latex. Browsing the internet gave me the information,

> Windows users get a pre-compiled binary of rtf2latex2e to be run 
>   from the command prompt.

But being a novice in using latex I don't know what the above statement means. Can anyone suggest how as to how to do this?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=pre-compiled+binary+of+rtf2latex2e&oq=pre-compiled+binary+of+rtf2latex2e&aqs=chrome..69i57.681j0j1&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8 You should find whtever is needed inside the zip file. See: http://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2latex2e/files/rtf2latex2e-win/2-2/

Comment: How to use this zip file? That is, how to actually covert an rtf file to latex using this file?

Comment: Put your rtf file also in the unzipped folder. Open command prompt in the unzipped folder (shift+right click and open command window here) . Then execute `rtf2latex2e -b yourfile.rtf` in the command window. Typeset the rtf2latexDoc.tex for more information, or print out the 
rtf2latexDoc.pdf file. They are in the documentation directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the current version `rtf2latex2e-2-2-2.zip` from [Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rtf2latex2e/) onto Windows 7. The odd question becomes clear, and the answer is DON'T follow the included instructions. Follow the instruction given by Harish as elaborated below.

1. Put your `rtf` file also in the unzipped folder.
2. Open command prompt in the unzipped folder.
3. Execute `rtf2latex2e -b 'filename'.rtf` (change options to suit your requirements)
4. The download doesn't include the manuals! Read at `http://latex2rtf.sourceforge.net/index.html` and get pdfs manual.

It would be great if an updated version like `latex2rtf-2.3.10_win` could be compiled, but until then the above does a good (none seem perfect) conversion job.